# Is it better to have a single insert or several updates For Fill in Data in a Table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, insert, sql-update

I have a table in which the IDs of all customers (About 10 million) along with information about their interests are recorded, for example, interest in books, movies, music, etc.and the structure of the table is as follows:

`InteresTable`:

| CustomerId | InterestedInbook | InterestedInMovies | InterestedInMusic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

If Customer Interes In Book Then the value Of The InterestedInBook would be 1.

For each of these interests, there is a separate table in which the number of interested customers is kept.

Now I want to fill in this table. Is it better to Left join the customer table with other tables using the query below the main table And insert at once?

```
INSERT INTO InteresTable (CustomerId, InterestedInbook, InterestedInMovie, InterestedInMusic)
    SELECT
        A.CustomerId, 
        CASE 
            WHEN B.CustomerNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS InterestedInbook,
        CASE
            WHEN B.CustomerNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS InterestedInMovie,
        CASE
            WHEN B.CustomerNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS InterestedInMusic
    FROM
        Customer A
    LEFT JOIN
        BookInt B ON A.CustomerNumber = B.CustomerNumber
    LEFT JOIN
        MovieInt C ON A.CustomerNumber = C.CustomerNumber
    LEFT JOIN
        MusicInt D ON A.CustomerNumber = D.CustomerNumber
```

Or is it better to read the customer ID from the main table once and then fill in the column values several times using the update Like Below:

```
INSERT INTO InteresTable (CustomerId)
    SELECT A.CustomerId
    FROM Customer A
-----
UPDATE a
SET InterestedInbook = 1 
FROM InteresTable A 
JOIN BookInt B ON a.CustomerNumber = B.CustomerNumber
---
UPDATE a
SET InterestedInMovies = 1 
FROM InteresTable A 
JOIN MovieInt B ON a.CustomerNumber = B.CustomerNumber
---
UPDATE a
SET InterestedInMusic = 1 
FROM InteresTable A 
JOIN MusicInt B ON a.CustomerNumber = B.CustomerNumber
```

Comment: If you only expect a handful of updates in the second version, then it _might_ be more performant than the first update join.  Otherwise, just use the single update join statement.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: In the second step you can use one statement join tables and update rather than 3 update stmts.

Comment: @Roshan Yes But If I use One Statement, I Should Use Left Join Instead Of Inner Join

Comment: Why exactly do you need to "optimize" a query that has a single use? And your schema (guessing - because you posted none) seems very odd since I would expect any "interest" table to have multiple rows per customer. Perhaps a view would be a better solution than duplicating millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Though requirement is not 100% clear to me.

Second option is very neat and tidy and easy to debug.
No of Sql statement never matter for performance.

Suppose a person has more than one interest then First option will fail ??